# Change background color of added tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My top-most cell in my table has a textfield that's used to add a new name to the tableview. I have it so that the added name animates in from below the textfield. What I would like is to have each new cell to have a different background color than the existing cells.

I've tried

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:nil];
```

but it doesn't do anything. I think it may be because the new cell is transitioning in and it doesn't have any index yet. Not sure, but I know it doesn't work. Any ideas or examples from elsewhere?

--- **UPDATED** ---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TextFieldCell *customCell = (TextFieldCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TextCellID"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        if (customCell == nil) {
            NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextFieldCell" owner:nil    options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[TextFieldCell class]])
                    customCell = (TextFieldCell *)currentObject;
            }
        }

        customCell.nameTextField.delegate = self;
        cell = customCell;
    }

    else {
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [[self.peopleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] name];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Where I add the person's name:

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    // If the textfield isn't blank, go ahead and add the person
    if ([textField.text length] != 0) {

        // Create new person
        Person *addedPerson = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:[self context]];

        // Set person's information
        [addedPerson setName:[textField.text capitalizedString]];

        // Add the person to the beginning of the datasource array
        [self.peopleArray insertObject:addedPerson atIndex:0];

        // Get the person's name from the textfield so that I can add their name later
        TextFieldCell *textCell = [[TextFieldCell alloc] init];
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        textCell = (TextFieldCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

        // Set the label below the textfield to the text from the textfield above
        NSString *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ was added", [textField text]];
        textCell.addedNameLabel.text = label;

        // Clear textfield for next entry
        textField.text = @"";

        // Animation to insert the new person at the top of the tableview
        NSIndexPath *pathInsert = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
        NSArray *indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathInsert,nil];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

    }
}
```

Comment: Does the color stay in those cells for the life of the tableview, or is this more of a response that something happened? Also, can you post code where you're inserting your rows, and maybe your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Updated with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and where I add the person's name.

Comment: The question remains: "Does the color stay in those cells for the life of the tableview, or is this more of a response that something happened?", it's important to understand what you want to do because your goal isn't clear.

Comment: I would like them to stay colored while that view is present.